# Finding the mean given the PDF of the Pareto Distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expectation, density-function

I'm trying to determine the general PDF and Mean for the Pareto distribution description of the size of TCP packets, given that distribution's CDF:

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases}
1-\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)^a, & x > k\\ 
0, & \text{else.} \end{cases}$$

I found the PDF easily by taking the derivative.

$$\text{PDF} = F'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{ak^a}{x^{a+1}}, & x > k\\ 
0, & \text{else.} \end{cases}$$

The last part however, finding the mean, has stumped me, as the only way I can think of the find it given this information is via the following definition of the mean:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\,dx,$$

$f(x)$ being the PDF. This results in the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{ak^a}{x^{a+1}}dx = \left.\frac{ak^ax^{1-a}}{1-a}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

But the solutions manual has the mean as equal to $\frac{ak}{a-1}$, which I have to assume is a logical simplification of the antiderivative I calculated, but I can't figure out how to bridge that gap.

In other words, how does:

$$\left.\frac{ak^ax^{1-a}}{1-a}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$ simplify to $$\frac{ak}{a-1}?$$

Or am I not looking at this correctly?

Comment: The integration should be from $k$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Technically, you are (almost) right, it is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx$. However, $f(x)=0$ for $x\le k$, so $\int_{-\infty}^k xf(x)\,dx=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bounds are wrong. You neglected the condition 
$x>k.$
*Very* important.

Now, rework it and you will see that
$$E[X] = \int_{k}^\infty x\cdot\frac{ak^a}{x^{a+1}}\,dx = \frac{ak}{a-1}.$$

Comment: Aha! It's too often the little things. Much thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it happens. Good luck.